# TeXStudio throws an error when using build and view once the file is saved

Tags: errors, texstudio, bugs

I have this "Could not start the command: Build & View" error, with the difference to the existing questions, that it works for old files I created in the past. And for unsaved files. But once I save the tex file, it stops working and throws that error. Given that in the folders of the old files, tex always created a bunch of files like: .aux .log etc. and it didn't create that for the new documents, I could imagine it has something to do with this.

I didn't use TexStudio for some time, so when I started it today it prompted me with an update. I downloaded and executed the update without uninstalling the old version. Could that have something to do with it?

This is a code snippet which works in an unsaved document but throws the error if I save the tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    content...
\end{document}
```

EDIT: I tried the advice for the other questions anyway and it didn't work. Neither putting the explicit path for the pdfviewer, nor deleting the config file.

Latest try (Command line):

```
$ pdflatex ./SectionB.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9.6210 64-bit)
entering extended mode
! I can't write on file `SectionB.log'.
Please type another transcript file name: test.log
! I can't write on file `test.log'.
Please type another transcript file name:
```

On a different file it actually worked so I am not sure what is the problem...

UPDATE: So apparently the command pdflatex [file] works if the bash is in the user folder, but not if it is located where I want to store the file. It is in a google drive folder, so I wonder if that is a reason for it not to work.
Anyway so I generated the .log .aux and .pdf files in the user folder and put them in the google drive folder. Now the build and view doesn't throw the same error, but instead goes through without the popup, but the message window shows: process exited with errors. Looking at the log: SectionB.tex Warning No SectionB.aux
This is false. There is an .aux file in the same folder. It continues to show the same pdf without updating changes.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! You can help us to help you by providing the code for a small compilable document that shows your problem/ error message. Just edit your question and add missing code. Do you compiled with pdflatex?

Comment: @Bobyandbob the default of the build and view button, which is pdflatex as far as I know, so yes

Comment: @Bobyandbob If I save an old file with a new name the build and view doesn't work either

Comment: Does build or pdflatex without view work?

Comment: just the compile button? No not either.

Comment: Is LaTeX installed and in the system path? (That is, if you type `pdflatex` into a command prompt, do you get an error?)

Comment: no I get: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9.6210 64-bit)

Comment: Ok. Try compiling your MWE with the command line (by typing `pdflatex <filename>` from inside the containing folder). If that works, the problem is definitely with TeXStudio. Uninstalling and installing it should fix it.

Comment: This works, it generates all the files, so I guess the problem is with TeXStudio

Comment: Uninstalling and reinstalling did not work though @schtandard

Comment: Have you already tried to save your new file in a different location?

Comment: @samcarter yes just did :D

Comment: @FelixB. This sounds like a problem with the permissions of this google folder

Comment: yes just double checked by creating a file in a different folder on the disk (which works) so it is probably the drive folder. I like to put my documents in the cloud so I have access to it from wherever I want. Any idea what I have to do to make it work again? Because I think I remember that it worked last time. But maybe I just migrated my work at some point and that is why the old things "work". I don't remember if I edited the old stuff in the cloud aswell...

Comment: Oh interesting apparently google drive doesn't even sync anymore and is getting replaced by "backup and sync" https://lifehacker.com/google-drive-is-dead-heres-what-you-need-to-know-1802109518 - but that doesn't really change anything - the sync works again, but the error is still there.

Comment: @FelixB. maybe a question for https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-drive?

Comment: yeah probably - thank you everyone!

Comment: I had this problem with a filename having two consecutive spaces. After removing the extra one, it was fine.